# Look for Android USB driver for mag tablet

Tags: android, usb, device, tablet

I can't find my tablet device on the eclipse android device manager,
after a research I found out that the problem is that the android usb device is missing.
I am looking for Android USB driver for MAG Innovision MP973G, can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need specific driver for your device, you could use drivers provided with android sdk.

You need to locate installed android `<sdk>` path on your machine and follow 8 steps listed [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7) (for windows)